# How to add a image in the border of rectangular div

Tags: css, html

i have a div approx. of 730px in width and 50px in height . i want to add a image in the bottom of the div where div height finished..i mean after 50px height.
i have a query that for appending image in the bottom .
i have to take another div and give it a background image or any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

I made this sample using `position: relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/R67zM/2/

HTML:

```
<div  id="parent">
<div id="image">fff</div>
</div>
```

other content 
CSS:

```
​#parent {
 width: 750px;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;   
 /*height of the image*/
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#parent #image {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background: green; 
 /*height of the  parent */  
 top: 50px;
}
```